# How can I Launching vscode from command line in background?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using shell on linux.
I would like the a way that will launch vscode in the background such that my terminal is still in focus.
I don't want to show any output on my terminal,perhaps chould show in integrated terminal which inside vscode.
[image: output]

Is someone can help me ?Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add an `&` at the end (see: [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control)), you probably also want to [redirect the output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output).  If you would like to log it, redirect to a file like this `&> vscode.log`, but if you want to ignore it, `&> /dev/null` (this is called a null device, see [this page](https://www.linuxshelltips.com/what-is-dev-null-in-linux/) for more).  So the final command is something like this: `code . &> /dev/null &`.